# How to separate a Series containing NaNs into two by length of defined elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Series object:

```
0    1211.0
1    2214.0
2    1317.0
3       NaN
4       NaN
5     812.0
Name: Time, Length: 6, dtype: float64
```

I want to get two separate Series from it:

```
0        12
1        22
2        13
3       NaN
4       NaN
5         8
Name: Hours, Length: 6, dtype: float64

0        11
1        14
2        17
3       NaN
4       NaN
5        12
Name: Minutes, Length: 6, dtype: float64
```

I have defined two functions:

```
def hours(col):
    hours = str(int(col)).strip()[:-2]
    return hours

def minutes(col):
    minutes = str(int(col)).strip()[-2:]
    return minutes
```

I have thought of something like this, but it does't work because of NaNs:

```
hours = Time.apply(hours)
minutes = Time.apply(minutes)
```

What should I do to make this function work the way I want them to?

Comment: You can replace NaN by nana, then replace it back

Comment: Why not just add an "if is NaN" in your functions?

Comment: Simple maths turned out to be a better option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use some math -

```
series1, series2 = s//100, s-100*(s//100)
series1.name = 'Hours'
series2.name = 'Minutes'
```

Sample run -

```
In [424]: s  # input series
Out[424]: 
0    1211.0
1    2214.0
2    1317.0
3       NaN
4       NaN
5     812.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64

In [425]: series1, series2 = s//100, s-100*(s//100)
     ...: series1.name = 'Hours'
     ...: series2.name = 'Minutes'
     ...: 

In [426]: series1
Out[426]: 
0    12.0
1    22.0
2    13.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     8.0
Name: Hours, dtype: float64

In [427]: series2
Out[427]: 
0    11.0
1    14.0
2    17.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    12.0
Name: Minutes, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I didn't know that it is possible to do maths like this with a Series. It turned out to be much simpler that I have thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.Time=df.Time.fillna('NANA').astype(str)
df['Hour']=df.Time.str[:-4]
df['Min']=df.Time.str[-4:-2]
df.replace({'NANA':np.nan,'NA':np.nan,'':np.nan})

Out[144]: 
     Time  Min Hour
0  1211.0   11   12
1  2214.0   14   22
2  1317.0   17   13
3     NaN  NaN  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN
5   812.0   12    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
Using time,

```
time = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0], format = '%H%M')
series1 = time.dt.hour
series2 = time.dt.minute

series

0    12.0
1    22.0
2    13.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     8.0

series2

0    11.0
1    14.0
2    17.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    12.0
```

Using str methods

```
series1 = df['col'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0].str[-2:].replace('an', np.nan)
series2 = df['col'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0].str[-4:-2].replace('n', np.nan)

series1

0     11
1     14
2     17
3    NaN
4    NaN
5     12

series2

0     12
1     22
2     13
3    NaN
4    NaN
5      8
```